# Get the desired result in function postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have data in postgresql-12:

```
 create table test (p01 int, p02 text, p03 boolean);
 insert into test values (111,'abc',false),(222,'sql',true),(333,'xyz',false);
```

I can get json:

```
 select json_agg(to_json(test)) from test;
--------------------------------------------
[{"p01":111,"p02":"abc","p03":false}, {"p01":222,"p02":"sql","p03":true}, {"p01":333,"p02":"xyz","p03":false}]

 or
 select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(p01)||to_jsonb(p02)||to_jsonb(p03)) from test;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[111, "abc", false], [222, "sql", true], [333, "xyz", false]]
```

But how can i get in function plpgsql? (result_1):

```
111, "abc", false, 222, "sql", true, 333, "xyz", false
```

so that later I can get (result_2)

```
 "1":111, "2":"abc", "3":false, "4":222, "5":"sql", "6":true, "7":333, "8":"xyz", "9":false
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            for example: json_object('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}', result_1)
```

If the second result is possible without first, this is also interesting, but the first result is needed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need to write a function to get this?

```
with step1 as (
  select jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(p01)||to_jsonb(p02)||to_jsonb(p03)))) as item
    from test
)
select jsonb_agg(item)
  from step1
;

                        jsonb_agg                         
----------------------------------------------------------
 [111, "abc", false, 222, "sql", true, 333, "xyz", false]
(1 row)
```

This can be further simplified and have explicit ordering enforced as follows:

```
select jsonb_agg(val order by p01, n) 
  from test
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_build_array(p01, p02, p03)) 
         with ordinality as x(val, n);

                        jsonb_agg                         
----------------------------------------------------------
 [111, "abc", false, 222, "sql", true, 333, "xyz", false]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Mike Organek, want to get an array javascript with elements: 111, "abc", false, 222, "sql", true, 333, "xyz", false ... as example.

Comment: @Alex  That is exactly what this query returns.

Comment: Mike Organek, This is a quick thing for a complex query of 12 table fields 6_join and sorting ORDER BY id ASC ? Thanks.

Comment: @Alex  The only way to tell is to benchmark it.  This rearrangement this does should not cost much compared to the execution of your complex query since this part touches only the results of your complex query.